# Sydney bus routes kml or csv or GIS datasets

Tags: geospatial, public-transport, kml

I am trying to import Sydney bus routes into a google map. Are there kml, csv or GIS datasets publicly available?

I couldn't find anything on data.nsw.gov.au or data.gov.au.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the Sydney GTFS-Files: https://transitfeeds.com/p/transport-for-nsw/237

The `stops.txt` contains the coordinates of the stops and the `shapes.txt` should contain the shapes of the lines.

You can use [gtfs2geojson](https://github.com/tmcw/gtfs2geojson) to convert the GTFS-Shapes to GeoJSON